# Suppressing Java Findbugs error (EI_EXPOSE_REP)

Tags: java, date, findbugs

I have a Java gettor method that looks like the following:

```
import java.util.Date;
//...
public Date getSomeDate() {
  return someDate;
}
```

and Findbugs reports that this exposes a mutable object: "May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object".
I changed the code to this:

```
import java.util.Date;
//...
public Date getSomeDate() {
  return new Date(someDate.getTime());
}
```

but Findbug still reports the same vulnerability. What more can I do to suppress/fix this problem? I am running Findbugs 1.3.9 in the IntellJ 10 Findbugs plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just realized that Findbugs analyzes **compiled** code (`.class` files), not source code. After rebuilding and re-running Findbugs, the problem went away.

Comment: I've been the victim of the same situation :) - spending 15 minutes wondering why my change didn't fix the error, and then realizing that I didn't rebuild.

Comment: @Rob Hruska: Took me about the same amount of time :-).

Answer (score 0):

No,we need to clone that object using below code :

```
public Date getSomeDate() {
  return new Date(someDate.getTime()).clone();
}
```

Comment: Using `new Date` *and* `clone` is too much xD